# How to query which users are using which certificates in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, certificate

I would like to know which users a certificate is used by.  I tried to do this query but got no results:

```
SELECT 
    master.sys.sql_logins.name,
    sys.certificates.name
FROM 
    master.sys.sql_logins 
INNER JOIN 
    sys.certificates 
    ON master.sys.sql_logins.sid = sys.certificates.sid
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please, tag your SQL Server version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That information is not exactly available and *may* be a security risk if it was, because essentially you'd need to know the public keys used with that **certificate**. This [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14217427/5059085) may be relevant and essentially agrees with my previous statement.

Taking a step back, these are the things you can derive though:

1. If your **certificate** was generated for a specific database, then all **principals** within that database are applicable to that **certificate**. You should be able to see which **principals** are mapped to the given database **certificate** by querying [`sys.database_principals`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-database-principals-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) `WHERE type = 'C'` as [discussed here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/2220/150011).
2. You should be able to get the **principal** of who owns a given **certificate** by using the `principal_id` to join to the [`sys.server_principals` view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-server-principals-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to get the **principal** `name`.